# How can I find out from which library my R object is from?

Tags: r, namespaces, libraries, bioconductor

I am still a bit puzzled by how namespaces are handled in R. In particular, I work with the [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org) ecosystem, where lot's of stuff from various libraries that I didn't explicitly load are being called in the background.
Concretely, I am using the `oligo` package to read in `.cel` files and it returns me an `HTAFeatureSet` object, of which I have no idea from which package it comes from. A simple google search wasn't very helpful either, I just get results on how to use these objects but not from which library it is from.

> Is there a function in R, similar to `?` or `class` that returns the library of an object, so I can read more about the idea behind this object?

Comment: `oligo` is already the name of the package I am using, so `help(oligo)` just yields "No documentation for ‘oligo’ in specified packages and libraries: you could try ‘??oligo’". The command `??oligo` wasn's useful either. Now, coming from other programming languages I would typically assume that my `HTAFeatureSet` class is simply from the package I used in the first place, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be true when working with the Bioconductor environment...

Comment: I am not sure who down-voted, my guess is your question sounds a bit vague. HTAFeatureSet is from the package oligo. it sets the class when you read in the cel files. https://rdrr.io/bioc/oligo/src/R/read.celfiles.R . unfortunately not much documentation about what methods can be applied.

Comment: I cannot install the package, but from https://rdrr.io/bioc/oligo/src/R/methods-HtaFeatureSet.R I think you can use rma() and stArrayPmInfo() and maybe others

Comment: Instead of `??oligo` try `??HTAFeatureSet`

Answer (score 1):

Without having installed package and examined the class structure, since we were not provided any example data: In general, any class will have methods associated with it.

```
methods(class = "HTAFeatureSet")
```

The list will then have accessible help pages through `?`, and the package where the function comes from will be listed in the upper left corner. E.g.

```
?print.HTAFeatureSet
```

Note that accessing help for any method available for the class will require that the class name is included in the search after the dot.

A very useful tool for learning to work with unfamiliar classes is to examine the structure of object.

```
str(yourvariablewithdata)
```

In analyses of genomic data in `R`, some classes store data in a form of a `list` or a `data.frame`. Such elements can then be directly manipulated with the respective methods. In other cases, such as class `DNAbin` (package `ape`), the data are stored in a bit-level format and data manipulation is easier using provided functions.

Answer (score -3):

Okay - I did some searching. So `Bioconductor` contains A LOT of packages. Like thousands. I'm not sure which ones you've imported. But I would start by looking here:
https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___Software for your `HTAFeatureSet`.
Since this seems to be a pretty niche work-space, there probably won't be much information outside of the Bioconductor website. Most R packages though will have a CRAN page associated with them.  You could try that also.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: Finding the website that houses the thousands of packages he blindly installed doesn't help?

Comment: OP knows it is from bioconductor and your answer does not show answer in any way, "How can I find out from which library my R project is from?" If you point towards the code or the generic function is created in the package, i would think this helps

Comment: Reading through the comments I now realized that I had a typo in my Title: I meant “R object” not “R project”! Guess that explains the confusion and the downvote...